# How to add a function to existing class/object in Python

Tags: python

I am reading a JSON object using Python. Below is the example.

```
var name = jsonObj['f_name'];
```

I want to define a function which can be directly called from jsonObj. Below is the pseudo code.

```
def get_attribute(key):
  if key in this
    return this[key]
  else
    return ''
```

And then I want to use this function as shown below.

```
jsonObj.get_attribute('f_name')
```

Let me know if this is possible. Please guide me on achieving this.

Comment: You could write a class that can be construded from the JSON data. Otherwise, python deserializes it into a `dict` which is meant to be used as a Map, not an object with methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arun** answers this, but as a fallback you can also use a function or another value. For example:

```
import json    
jsonObj=json.loads('{"f_name": "peter"}')

jsonObj.get('f_name')
# u'peter'

jsonObj.get('x_name','default')
# 'default'

jsonObj.get('x_name',jsonObj.get('f_name')) # or could just place it after the 
                                            # `get` with an or
# u'peter'
```

Comment: well explained  

Comment: Yes.. This helped. Is there any flavour of get which can get nested attributes as well. Like record['address']['postal_code'] ?

Comment: @NeerajKumar Yes, you could do `record.get('address', {}).get('postal_code')`

Comment: @David542 Thanks for helping me out. Just out of curiosity, is Python capable of providing functionality to define a function and attach it to an existing class or object. Please refer to the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `get`

```
>>> dictionary = {"message": "Hello, World!"}
>>> dictionary.get("message", "")
'Hello, World!'
>>> dictionary.get("test", "")
''
```